# MS Teams: Invoking Azure functions from Outgoing webhooks

Tags: azure-functions, microsoft-teams, webhooks

I have created Outgoing webhooks in teams and added my azure function url in callback url now at end of outgoing webhook I had copied my secret key from webhooks to Azure configuration so it can trust my bot

But now when i try to mention @webhook name in teams always throw exception an anyone let me know what i am missing

```
Sorry, there was a problem encountered with your request
```

Below is my Azure function code

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string name = req.Query["name"];

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;

    string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
        ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
}
```

Comment: Could you please confirm that your server and client authentication tokens are equal?

Comment: where to check this

Comment: looks i missed this step need to write custom code for server and client authentications?

Comment: Could you please refer below document and sample:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook?tabs=urljsonpayload%2Cdotnet

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/outgoing-webhook/csharp

Comment: i executed the code but unable to relate how my azure function should trigger any help

Answer (score 0):

You have to create HttpTrigger Azure function.
In your code the function is just HttpRequest function not HttpTrigger.

Refer below code for Azure HttpTrigger function:

```
[FunctionName("HttpTriggerCSharp")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]
    HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string name = req.Query["name"];

    string requestBody = String.Empty;
    using (StreamReader streamReader =  new  StreamReader(req.Body))
    {
        requestBody = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;

    return name != null
        ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
        : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
}
```

Refer below document for more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp

Comment: Thanks from learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/… github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/… i used sample c# solution and used ngrok for local dev environment now to execute Azure function where shall i write my code inside this sample solution or shall i directly excute it from from portal.azure.com

Comment: Could you please refer below doc for steps for execution:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp